# infwarerr.sty could not be found

Tags: packages

A few days ago I installed TeXstudio on my laptop and I got an error saying that it cannot find the file `infwarerr.sty`:

[image]

I decided to look for the file on the internet. I found a repository that was for the `infwarerr` library but when I downloaded the package the `.sty` file does not appear, only these files appear:

[image]

I only see these files and the `.sty` file is not there. What can I do?

Comment: that is the standard ctan distribution format but you should not be getting this package from an archive: it is a standard part of texlive and miktex (`/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty` or equivalent) so simply install it via your tex distribution, the mikex console or `tlmgr` or equivalent. (why is this tagged beamer?)

Comment: bu as far as I can understand the dialog you show, do you not simply want to click on "install"? It does not look like an error.

Comment: This is a good question. I'm trying to add a GitHub workflow that runs `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex` and I get a very similar error that infwarrer.sty can't be found (workflow fails). I think it's included by /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty, which IS found. The workflow is being run on Ubuntu. When I used Ubuntu pkg search, no pkg contained that file. It's on my system (Manjaro) and also is included in texlive-latex-base (Debian pkg). @albert, in your case, I'd suggested opening a ticket in the texstudio issues. You're using Windows?

Comment: @ArchStanton You pinged me because of the issue, I only correct some spelling errors . The right person to ping / recommend to open the ticket is the issuer of the issue.

Comment: Albert, thanks for letting me know of my error... :) @harold-julian-np, please note my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Update your MiKTeX packages as that worked for me:

[image]